# Share image plus text via Whatsapp with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, share, whatsapp, react-native-ios

I am working on a react native app and one of my needs is to be able to share via Whatsapp, a png image (created from a svg) plus some text in the message. I have achieved this on Android using [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) but when I try it on iOS, the message is populated with the provided text but the image is ignored. I have also tried with [Share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share) from react-native but the result is the same.

I have tried this sharing directly a base64 image **(data:image/png;base64,*image_data*)** as well as saving the created image and add the **path as the url** but the result is always the same.

The only way to make this work on iOS (with both react-native-share and Share) is to omit the message, but the text is needed in the requirement.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Versions:

- React Native - 0.55.0
- react-native-share - 1.1.2

> As a side note, the sharing process on Twitter, Email, SMS and some other apps is working correctly.

Code sample:

```
const base64Data = this.state.uri
const dir = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/tmp_${moment().valueOf()}.png`

RNFS.writeFile(dir, base64Data, 'base64').then(async () => {
  const options = {
    url: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file://${dir}` : dir,
    message: '' // By omitting the message, whatsapp shows the image
  }
  try {
    await Share.open(options)
    // Delete file when share action is completed
    await RNFS.unlink(dir)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err.message)
})
```

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: Sorry... not at all. We had to go with another approach... We ended up sending the web link that contains the image

Comment: Thanks. 2020 and still cannot share an image with text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905965/5079876 -> Please check out this answer. I hope it helps.