# react-native: share api passing base64 string instead of image to WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hey i am struggling with sharing an base64 image via WhatsApp. In iOS also Android the actual base 64 is been shared instead of the image.

If I use iMessage or Email (iOS) the base64 images is been converted and displayed as expected. In Android using Email for sharing displays just the base64 string. Did anyone else face the same issue?

**I am using react-native ~0.55.2**

[react-native Share API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image, Text, StyleSheet, View, Share, Button} from 'react-native';

class ShareClass extends Component {

  onClick() {
    Share.share({
      message: REACT_ICON, //for whats app
      url: REACT_ICON, // for other applications
       title: 'Wow, did you see that?'
    }, {
      // Android only:
      dialogTitle: 'Share BAM goodness',
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <Button 
          title ="Testing the Share Button"
          onPress = {this.onClick}> 
          </Button>

          <Text>Testing the display of base64 image</Text>
          <Image source = {{uri:REACT_ICON, width:100, height: 100}} />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});


const REACT_ICON = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

export default ShareClass
```

Comment: single or multiple images sharing using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure how it will work with inbuilt Share functionality added by react-native. But using `react-native-share` worked for me.

I have found a working workaround for this problem. Currently, I also use it in one of my applications. You can directly plug and play the below onClick function on a button press.

**RNFS.downloadFile**, downloads the remote image using URL and save it to a path.
**RNFS.readFile**, converts the locally saved file data to base64 which is supported directly by Whatsapp and other applications.

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

async onClick(url, id){
        const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${id}.jpg`;
        await RNFS.downloadFile({ fromUrl: url, toFile: `file://${path}` }).promise
            .then((res) => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return err;
            });
        RNFS.readFile(`file://${path}`, 'base64').then((res) => {
            let shareOptionsUrl = {
                title: 'My Application',
                message: 'Use my application',
                url: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${res}`, // use image/jpeg instead of image/jpg
                subject: 'Share information from your application'
            };
            Share.open(shareOptionsUrl);
        })
    }
```

**Url** is the image remote URL and **id** is some unique identifier for that image.

Comment: I used npx react-native link to Linkin the library. Otherwise it will show error. Everything work as aspected.